# Display Wordpress latest posts on a non Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I currently have a non-Wordpress website: [asia-hr.com](https://asia-hr.com) and I also have one subdomain which is a Wordpress Website [blog.asia-hr.com](https://blog.asia-hr.com).

I am now working of the homepage of asia-hr.com and I would like to add a section to display the 3 most recent articles of my blog.

What I have is that:

```
<?php if (have_posts() ):?>
  <?php while(have_posts()):the_post(); ?>

<div id="post">

  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <div class="byline">Escrito por <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
    el <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_time('l F d, Y'); ?></a>
  </div>
  <?php the_content('Read More..'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <p>No posts were found. Sorry!")</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Obviously, I am getting the error `Call to undefined function have_posts()`, how can I let my homepage access to my blog WP?

Comment: Of course, you can't use WordPress functions outside WordPress. One way to retrieve your latest posts would be via the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/), check the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As long as asia.hr.com and blog.asia-hr.com are in the same hosting account, you can include `wp-load.php` which gives you access to all functions of WordPress:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); // Don't load theme support functionality
require( './wp-load.php' );
```

You will need to set the correct path to include the `wp-load.php` file.

The first line also tells WordPress to load not the Theme files. If the files are necessary for your requirements, then remove that line.